# Python - Cannot pass variables between methods in a Class

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and was doing a classes exercise where I have to create a Student class which supports taking marks for 5 subjects from the user and returning the percentage. Both of these have to be done by creating two different methods. I have tried multiple times yet there seems to be a flaw in my logic so how can I fix this? I know if I had passed the subjects 1-5 as attributes in init class, the code would have worked but I have been instructed to have separate methods. The error I am getting when calling perc() is -  "setMarks" is not defined. Here is my code:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, rollno, stream):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = rollno
        self.stream = stream

    def setMarks(self):

        sub1 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 1: "))
        sub2 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 2: "))
        sub3 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 3: "))
        sub4 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 4: "))
        sub5 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 5: "))
        totalmarks = sub1 + sub2 +sub3 + sub4 + sub5


    def getStream(self):
        if self.stream == "A":
            print("Arts")
        elif self.stream == "C":
            print("Commerce")
        elif self.stream == "S":
            print("Science")
        else:
            print("Invalid stream")

    def perc(self):
        totalmarks = setMarks()

        percentage = ( totalmarks / 500) * 100 
        print(f"{self.name} has a percentage of: {percentage}" )
```

Comment: You are not `return`ing anything from `setMarks()`, so `totalmarks` in `perc()` is always `None`.

Comment: You need `return totalmarks`

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same name error as I was before

Answer (score 0):

You'll need

```
def setMarks(self):

    sub1 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 1: "))
    sub2 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 2: "))
    sub3 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 3: "))
    sub4 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 4: "))
    sub5 = int(input("Enter marks for subject 5: "))
    totalmarks = sub1 + sub2 +sub3 + sub4 + sub5
    return totalmarks
    # ^^^
```

Additionally, within a class in `Python`, you need to call the functions with `self` (technically it could be anything, e.g. `cls`, `mypointer`, `whatever`) before, so instead of

```
    totalmarks = setMarks()
```

you need to write

```
    totalmarks = self.setMarks()
```

Comment: Hey umm I tried it and still I am getting the same NameError

Comment: @zsasz: Updated the answer, you need to write `self.setMarks()`.

Comment: Hey  thanks it's working finally but I have to input my marks all over again when I call the perc method. Any idea how I can fix that?